# Is it possible to run a Windows app within a console window?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, c#-4.0, console

I have a Windows app that I've written in C# 4 and WPF; I've now been asked if I can add a commandline parameter (e.g. /console) that would force it to run as a console app so it can be run by a task scheduler.

Is this possible with modern apps? Or do I need to create a separate console app?

**UPDATE**: can I just emphasise that this is a **WPF** application. There is no convenient `static void Main(string[] args)` entry point to hook into. But the PM would still like the app to have the ability to run from the commandline...

**FINAL UPDATE**: the trick, as pointed out by @RodH257, is that the WPF app codegens the expected static void Main. You can add your own class with a method of the same name and in the project build properties, set it as the startup object for the executable. You'll also need the [STAThread] attribute on the method so that WPF will run properly too.

Comment: FYI: Just wrote a huge post on how I figured out to open WPF windows, and also hide/show the console window.  The info was all over the place, so I decided to post how I got it working in my own project: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/479014/wpf-window-from-a-console-project/33441726#33441726

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either turn it into a console application and manually show the first WPF dialog. just as you would if you were creating a DLL and starting a WPF window, as per below

```
 static class Program
{
    static void Main(params string[] args)
    {
        if (args.Length > 0)
        {
           //do stuff here
            return;
        }
          Window1 window = new Window1();
          window.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

OR, have a look at this link for editing the entrypoint on your current WPF project and act based on arguments
[How to write custom Main method for a WPF application?](http://www.infosysblogs.com/microsoft/2008/09/how_to_write_custom_main_metho.html)

EDIT:
Updated the post to make it more clear for the exact situation described.

Comment: Unfortunately as stated, the application is a WPF application and doesn't have a convenient Main entry point.

Comment: I've updated my answer to be more clear. Create a Console Application project as your entry point then create a new instance of your Window.

Comment: Many thanks - your link pointed to the best solution (approach #3, if you were wondering).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, a Windows GUI app has a `Main` just like a console app.  So the trick is to do some pre-processing `Main` before starting the UI loop.  It should be noted that if you want to use the console from inside an app compiled as a .NET "Windows Application" in Visual Studio, you will have to [`AllocConsole`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) manually since you won't get one by default.

[This MSDN forum thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/fd89cf64-eab4-4cc5-8f35-74ec848d8a60/) discusses some more about "hybrid console/GUI apps".

Answer (score 2):

You can launch it from within a console app using a dos command, but, unless you modify the startup routine (in `Main()`)   when it runs it is going to load and display the main window... If you don't want the main window to be displayed, just recode the main routine so that a `Main()` parameter disables that option...

Instead of this:

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
       Application.Run(new MainForm());
    }
```

code this:

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(params string[] args)
    {
         if(args.length <= 1)
              Application.Run(new MainForm());
         else if (args[1].StartsWith("C")) // "C" for "C"onsole version
              // Do whatever needs to be done to start 
              //    functionality for console app version 
    }
```

Then, when you run it, add the /C switch:

```
   C:\MyCurrentDirectory>MyWinFormsApplicationName.exe /C
```

Comment: Unfortunately as stated, the application is a WPF application and doesn't have a convenient Main entry point.

Answer (score 0):

It's extremely dependent upon how the program was originally written.

If you have written your logic in a loosly coupled way, you can create another console application and reuse your logic there. It's manual programming/refactoring work.

Answer (score 0):

If it gets run by a task scheduler, you don't need any screen at all to  come up.  remove the startupuri and manually launch the windows depending on commmand line.

if its a console launched process, just do whatever processing you need.  Otherwise, launch your windows...

Comment: Prompted by your suggestion, I found http://www.dutton.me.uk/2011/02/21/how-to-handle-command-line-arguments-in-wpf-applications/, however I found that if I try to call Console.WriteLine then no output appears. Would I have to use something like log4net to get output?

Comment: thats what I tend to do for server based things I want to run in the background.... or sometimes log something into a database.

Answer (score -1):

Here's an [article/code sample showing how it's done](http://www.rootsilver.com/2007/08/how-to-create-a-consolewindow).  The build type is important.  Your compiler only lets you have one build target (e.g., GUI, command-line).

Comment: Unfortunately as stated, the application is a WPF application and doesn't have a convenient Main entry point.