# Add a WPF ProgressBar to a C# Console Application

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-console

Long story short, due to shifting business requirements, I need to be able to show the end user the progress of a file archival process controlled by a C# console application. The console app essentially gets a list of local files from a db and then copies them to an archive location. This was originally supposed to be a background process triggered by a scheduled task. Now, however, users can launch it manually with various arguments from the command line, so I was recently tasked with letting the user know the status of the archive process.

I thought I would just use a WPF ProgressBar control for this, but now I'm going in circles trying to sort out the best way to do this. I've been working with the answer from @JamesWilkins here: [WPF window from a Console project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479014/wpf-window-from-a-console-project)

I've added the ProgressBar window to the console application, and added the following to the Main method in the console(super simplified for clarity):

```
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    // EXISTING CONSOLE LOGIC
    ParseCommandLineArgs();
    Configure();

    // ADDED
    InitializeWindows(); // opens the WPF window and waits here

    // EXISTING CONSOLE LOGIC 
    BeginArchival();        
}

static void InitializeWindows()
{
    WinApp = new Application();
    WinApp.Run(ProgressBar = new ProgressBar()); // blocking call
}
```

Then in the ProgressBar.xaml code behind:

```
public partial class ProgressBar : Window
{
    public ProgressBar()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ProgressBar_OnContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
        worker.ProgressChanged += worker_ProgressChanged;

        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        // foreach file that is archived, report progress to the 
        // ProgressBar.
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            (sender as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress(i);
        }
    }

    private void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, 
        ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        PbArchiveStatus.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }
}
```

The process waits at the InitializeWindows() method until the progress bar is closed, so it doesn't hit any of the archive logic that I need the progress bar to show progress for. It seems that I essentially need to put all of the existing console logic inside the ProgressBar.worker_DoWork() method, but at this point my brain is starting to hurt so I thought I'd reach out.

Am I on the right track, or is there a better way to add a GUI-based progress bar to a console utility? Let me know if I can clarify anything at all.

Comment: Whats normally shown on the console window? Is it just an inhouse app that you could make your own type of progress bar in the console, eg [|||||||||||                       ]

Comment: Can’t you just write the progress to the console? That way you wouldn’t turn a console application (which explicitly works *without* a GUI, e.g. via a remote session) into a crippled Windows application. If the WPF progress bar is already decided on, can’t you just turn your application into a proper Windows application instead of doing half console half windowed?

Comment: The only reason I made it a console application originally is because they wanted it to run as a scheduled task. They ended up removing that requirement and said they wanted to be able to run it manually. I actually did have a text-based progress bar going in the console. The problem with that was that if the user clicked on the console window at any point, it essentially broke the progress bar. I just decided that a gui-based progress bar looked better and was the cleaner, more fool-proof solution, but it turned out to be a little more involved than I thought originally.

Comment: To be clear, I realize that this is not ideal, but I need to be able to keep everything the same as far as the end user is concerned(running the executable with command line arguments).

Comment: I can change the project output type to Windows Application, as you said @poke, but that still leaves me wondering how best to go about integrating the progress bar.

Comment: I was more thinking of starting a proper (new) windows application project, creating a proper (simple) UI there and moving the application logic into it then.

Comment: _"It seems that I essentially need to put all of the existing console logic inside the ProgressBar.worker_DoWork() method"_ -- well, you need to put it _somewhere_. It's not really clear what answer you need. Fact is, you should decide whether you are writing a console program or a WPF program and not mix the two. You can do progress indication in a console program, just not with WPF features. If you want to use WPF features, you really should just make a regular GUI program that uses WPF. As long as you stick to one or the other, there is ample information already on progress indication

Comment: And to be clear: yes, you can show GUI from a console program, but at the end of the day, it never really works right. It's best to avoid that sort of Frankenstein approach.