# Why no text colors after using CreateFile("CONOUT$" ...) to redirect the console back to the active screen buffer?

Tags: c#, console-application

I had an old app based off of this setup (but more advanced): https://stackoverflow.com/a/33441726/1236397

Basically, it runs, processes stuff, and closes, and only opens a window if it needs to (runs via another application).  Since porting this to Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 10 the output window failed to work. After a bit more investigation it appears the issue was related to the standard output being redirected for *non*-console applications (output type must be "Windows Application" to initially hide all windows).  In this scenario, while debugging, there is no text output, which requires resetting the redirected output. This is done using `CreateFile("CONOUT$", ...)` to get and redirect the console back to the display buffer output.

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)] //, EntryPoint = "CreateFileW", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall
private static extern IntPtr CreateFileW(
      string lpFileName,
      UInt32 dwDesiredAccess,
      UInt32 dwShareMode,
      IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes,
      UInt32 dwCreationDisposition,
      UInt32 dwFlagsAndAttributes,
      IntPtr hTemplateFile
     );

const UInt32 GENERIC_WRITE = 0x40000000;
const UInt32 GENERIC_READ = 0x80000000;
const UInt32 OPEN_EXISTING = 0x00000003;

const int STD_INPUT_HANDLE = -10;
const int STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = -11;
const int STD_ERROR_HANDLE = -12;

var outFile = CreateFileW("CONOUT$", GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_WRITE, IntPtr.Zero, OPEN_EXISTING, /*FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL*/0, IntPtr.Zero);
var safeHandle = new SafeFileHandle(outFile, true);
SetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE, outFile);
var fs = new FileStream(safeHandle, FileAccess.Write);
var writer = new StreamWriter(fs) { AutoFlush = true };
Console.SetOut(writer);
```

This works; however, there is no color support.  How can colors be enabled?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As it turns out, after much digging, it seems there's a mode that does not get set when the application runs in  "Windows Application" mode:

`ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_INPUT` ([doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolemode#ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_INPUT))

This is how to set it:

```
if (GetConsoleMode(outFile, out var cMode))
    SetConsoleMode(outFile, cMode | ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_INPUT);
```

However, it still would not work, and this is where my issue was.  That `if` statement will ALWAYS fail because only `GENERIC_WRITE` was specified for `CreateFileW()`!  Turns out `GENERIC_READ` ALSO needs to be set, otherwise, you cannot read the current mode. The `CreateFileW` line should be this:

```
var outFile = CreateFileW("CONOUT$", GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_WRITE, IntPtr.Zero, OPEN_EXISTING, /*FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL*/0, IntPtr.Zero);
```

My final code is different from this, but I wrapped up an example here for others if needed:

```
var outFile = CreateFileW("CONOUT$", GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_WRITE, IntPtr.Zero, OPEN_EXISTING, /*FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL*/0, IntPtr.Zero);
var safeHandle = new SafeFileHandle(outFile, true);
SetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE, outFile);
var fs = new FileStream(safeHandle, FileAccess.Write);
var writer = new StreamWriter(fs) { AutoFlush = true };
Console.SetOut(writer);
if (GetConsoleMode(outFile, out var cMode))
    SetConsoleMode(outFile, cMode | ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_INPUT);
```

A lot of time was wasted trying to figure this out from info scattered everywhere, so I hope this helps save someone else time. ;)

Comment: I've tried this code with no success.  I get an invalid parameter error when I call SetConsoleMode with the ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_INPUT flag.

Comment: The document states “When a console is created, all input modes except ENABLE_WINDOW_INPUT are enabled by default.”. It doesn’t say any other restrictions, so perhaps you’re using an enum with a wrong value? Or adding them incorrectly (they are flags)? Are you using C# with Visual Studio on Windows 7, or 10? Also, are you creating a console app, or something else that is trying to open a console window?

Comment: I'm on Visual Studio 2017 (v15.8.1), .NET 4.7.2, Windows 10 (v10.0.17134.228). I'm creating the console using AllocConsole.  The flag I'm OR'ing is 0x200 (I confirmed this to be ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_INPUT on MSDN). The code I'm using is nearly identical to yours in that I'm calling GetConsoleMode, and ORing the output value (which comes back as 0x3) with 0x200 when passing to SetConsoleMode.  Maybe this is a bug in this particular version of Win 10?

Comment: I'm also using CreateFileW in the same way as you (Generic Read/Write are specified correctly).  If that wasn't working, I'd most likely not be getting any output at all.

Comment: What is your project type? (Check the project properties) In my case I was creating a windows app (not console) where the console window doesn’t show by default.

Comment: The application is a windows app.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but if this is still an issue and you are able to share the project I can test it out for you on my end.

Comment: Here's a link to the code in question: https://github.com/Tape-Worm/Gorgon/blob/3.0/Gorgon/Gorgon.Windows/Diagnostics/LogProviders/GorgonLogConsoleProvider.cs